# Create a timer event in c++ /clr

Tags: c++, timer, clr

So, I am trying to create a timer event (in C++ /clr this time) but I don't know how to define a new event, this is what I got:

```
namespace hook
{
    public ref class Tick
    {
    private: 
        static System::Timers::Timer^ aTimer;

    public: 
        event EventHandler^ OnTick;
        int Interval;

        Tick()
        {
            aTimer = gcnew System::Timers::Timer(Interval);
            aTimer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(Tick::execute);
        }

        static void execute(Object^ source, ElapsedEventArgs^ e)
        {
            this->OnTick(this, new EventsArg()); // Wrong
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an instance member (OnTick) from a static method, that cannot work.  Remove the *static* keyword to get:

```
 void execute(Object^ source, ElapsedEventArgs^ e)
```

Which requires that you change the event subscription code, you must create a delegate that stores *this*:

```
 aTimer->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(this, &Tick::execute);
```

One more mistake, you misspelled EventArgs.  It is so common to pass that it has a pre-cooked object, returned by Empty.  Cuts down on the garbage:

```
 this->OnTick(this, EventArgs::Empty);
```

Watch out for writing code that just duplicates the original class without adding value.